# How to display two table columns per row in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to display data, two columns per row during my foreach. I would like my result to look like the following:
MODEL:

```
     public function getAllRecord($table, $criteria){
        if($criteria != '')
            $this->db->where($criteria);
        $query = $this->db->get($table);
        if($query->num_rows() >= 1)
            return $query->result();
        else
            return null;
    }
```

CONTROLLER:

```
$data['x']= $this->Queries->getAllRecord('tableImages','');
```

VIEW:

```
    foreach($x as $key => $value){
     echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td>'.$value->image.'</td>'
     echo '</tr>' }
```

and the out put should be:

```
 <table>
 <tr><td>Image1</td><td>Image2</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Image3</td><td>Image4</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Image5</td><td>Image6</td></tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: why down vote my question?

Comment: Where is your data example? where is an attempted foreach? model ... controller ...

Comment: Provide some sample code where you need some help.

Comment: I've added the example @YogeshSalvi

Comment: I've added the example @Alex

Comment: That's just not enough. Re read my first comment to give you an idea of what you need to provide. Also read stacks mvce guidelines

Comment: @Alex is this okay?

Comment: yes, perfect. seems like u've already got an answer too!

Comment: @dain, if my solution as resolved your issue, you can mark my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are having one dimensional array and want to show two records in each row of table.

You can chunk your array with `array_chunk' and iterate on resulted array,

You can try something like:

```
$x = array_chunk($x, 2);
foreach ($x as $value) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$value[0]->image.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$value[1]->image.'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: Love this solution. After looking at it I realized I could refactor a code block I had where I was essentially using the modulus operator to perform a similar task with much more code. Thanks - forgot about this gem ;)

Comment: @Alex Welcome :)